# Excel vba - issue with copy and paste non mathes to the third worksheet (after compare two ranges & find non matches)

Tags: compare, copy-paste

I have two worksheets (Month1, and Month2). I am trying to finding non matches then copy and paste the non matches into the third worksheet (EndReport). However, it's not pasting at all maybe due to the codes... Can someone advise how I can modify my copy and paste codes to make it work... much thx!

```
'Search for Non-Matched IO Series of Month 2 and populate the data into EndReport

Dim iNON As Long
Dim arrSum As Variant, arrUsers As Variant
Dim cUnique As New Collection

'Put the name range from "Month2" in an array
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month2")
    arrSum = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

'"Convert" the array to a collection (unique items)
For iNON = 1 To UBound(arrSum, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    cUnique.Add arrSum(iNON, 1), CStr(arrSum(iNON, 1))
Next iNON

'Get the users array
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month1")
    arrUsers = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

'Check if the value exists in the Month1 sheet
For iNON = 1 To cUnique.Count
    'if can't find the value in the users range, delete the rows
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cUnique(iNON), arrUsers, 1, False) = "#N/A" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month2").Cells
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cUnique(iNON)
            .Range("A3", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Copy
        End With


        Sheets("EndReport").Activate
        Sheets("EndReport").Select
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EndReport").Cells.Range("A3", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Paste Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Worksheets("EndReport").Range("A" & Worksheets("EndReport").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row & "").Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next iNON

'removes AutoFilter if one remains
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month2").AutoFilterMode = False
```